# html / js form for multiple file upload to remote server and zip

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms

I need something for my few colleagues photographers but i dont know how to do.

I need a html/js form because I can after recompile it in Adobe PhoneGap to create android app.
It should consists these fields:

1. Name
2. Phone
3. Email
4. Multiple file upload
5. Send

Files would be uploaded to my server for example www.mywwebsite.com/user-uploads/ and i should get notification on my email with link for zipped file with upload files so i can downloaded them.
Something like wetransfer.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: My mistake than. I tried something with https://fineuploader.com/ but with no success. Thank you for heads up

Comment: No worries, although please **[research your problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)** *before* asking for help on StackOverflow, and then update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions :)